How to autowire a Spring Boot bean depending on a request attribute?
I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I have two implementations of a particular service, a real one and a proxy one. The interface looks like this:
@Service
public interface RefundService {

    String checkHealth();
}

The proxy implementation looks like this:
@Service
@Qualifier("proxyRefundService")
public class ProxyRefundService implements RefundService {
    ...
}

Now, there's a controller which needs to use this service in order to fulfill it's duty. I'd like to use autowiring for this:
public RefundgwController(@Autowired @Qualifier(value = "proxyRefundService") RefundService refundService) {
    this.refundService = refundService;
    this.mapper = mapper;
}

What I'd like to do is, depending on the request IP, decide which instance of RefundService should be injected as part of the controller's creation.
One thing to clarify: I'm not a Java expert, I usually code in PHP so perhaps I'm confusing some concepts here. Any idea/comment is welcome.

Spring doesn't instantiate a controller per request. It instantiates it once, usually on start up, and then uses it for each and every incoming request. So what you want to do is not possible this way. You would need to instantiate your controller with both beans, and select the one to use dynamically per request, or use some other thing to choose the right bean per request. (There might be an advanced trick for this, but I can't think of it right now.)

Not exactly what you are looking for, but How to dynamically inject a service using a runtime "qualifier" variable? probably can help.

As another idea (more complicated) you can use request scoped controller, with request scoped DelegatingRefundService implements RefundService, autowire in it proxy and basic implementations and request - you can inject the request object in request scoped beans. Get the ip from the request and pick the correct implementation to delegate the operation to.

Thank you all! @MarkRotteveel, that's what I was thinking after I wrote the question... a confusion between php and Java execution models. I guess I'll have to inject both and run some controller logic to choose... I was hoping to get it done outside of it so I didn't have to touch this class but ok
